# Banach-Mazur distance between $\ell^p$-norms

Tags: banach-spaces, linear-algebra, convexity

Let $E^n$ be the real or complex space of dimension $n$. If $N$ and $M$ are two norms over $E^n$, and if $A$ is an endomorphism, then 
$$\|A\|^M_N:=\sup_{x\ne0}\frac{M(Ax)}{N(x)}$$
is an operator norm of $A$.

The Banach-Mazur distance between $N$ and $M$ is 
$$d(N,M):=\log\inf_{A\in Aut(E)}\|A\|^M_N\|A^{-1}\|^N_M.$$
It is actually a semi-distance, with $d(N,M)=0$ iff one passes from $N$ to $M$ by a change of coordinates. Thus $d$ is a distance on some quotient space, in which there is only one Euclidian norm, for instance.

Let us define the usual $\ell^p$-norm by
$$\|x\|_p:=\left(\sum_j|x_j|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$
The $L^\infty$-norm is as usual.
It has been known for a long time that if $1\le p,q\le2$, or if $2\le p,q\le\infty$, then
$$d(\ell^p,\ell^q)=\left|\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}\right|\log n.$$
What is known if $1\le p\le2\le q\le+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 13):

I've just looked in the "Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces", Chapter 1, Section 8, which gives that  $$d(\ell^p,\ell^q) = \log\max(n^{|1/p-1/2|}, n^{|1/q-1/2|})$$ up to a constant (which seems hard to find!)  The argument is not entirely elementary, using cotype estimates.  I'd also look in Tomczak-Jaegermann's book "Banach-Mazur distances and finite-dimensional operator ideals" but I don't have that on my shelf right now.

Comment: This does not seem correct, because the distance is zero when $p=q$, whereas your formula gives $|1/p-1/2|\log n$ instead.

Comment: @Denis: Matt gave the formula for $p \le 2 \le q$ because that is what you asked for.  

BTW, it is conventional to define the B-M distance without the log, making the distance submultiplicative instead of subadditive, so the the B-M distance is the isomorphism constant between the two spaces.

Comment: @Bill : you are right.

@Matt : the Handbook only gives the inequality $\le$, and says that it is acccurate *up to an absolute constant*. The equality cannot be always valid, because in dimension $2$ one has $d(\ell^1,\ell^\infty)=0$ (whereas this is positive in dimension $\ge3$).

Comment: Yeah, I said "up to a constant" (but, sure, I meant _absolute_ constant).  And, yes, it's only valid for $p\leq 2\leq q$.

Comment: I was confused by $A=B$ up to a constant. I thought that it meant $A\equiv cB$. Now it becomes clear.


Comment: Is this a correct reading of the above: to compare $l^p$ with $l^q$, if $p$ and $q$ are on the same side of $2$, then the map $A = I$ is optimal.  If they are on opposite sides of $2$, then it's hard to find a recipe for an optimal linear map, but it's only boundedly suboptimal to compare them to the $l^2$ norm.

It shouldn't be hard to find optimal comparisons numerically in low dimensions. It would be interesting to see the optimal $A$ for some of these starting with dimension 3, e.g., what linear map best fits an octahedron inside the cube?  Are pictures available somewhere?

Comment: @Denis: With complex scalars, $d(\ell_1^2,\ell_\infty^2)>0$.  

@Bill Thurston:  For the upper bound, consider the case $n=2^k$ and the mapping from $\ell_p^n$ to $L_q^n$, $p\le 2 \le q$, that takes the unit vector basis to the Walsh basis.  (Here $L_q^n$ is $L_q(\mu)$ with $\mu$ the uniform probability on $\{1,...,n\}$).   


Comment: @Denis regarding "The equality cannot be always valid, because in dimension 2 one has $d(\ell^1,\ell^{\infty})=0$". Could one find $1\leq p <2<q<\infty$ s.t. the equality is not valid?

Comment: In addition I'd be interested to find $1 \leq p \leq 2 \leq q <+\infty$, $p< q$ s.t. $d(\ell^{p},\ell^{q})\neq (1/p−1/q)\log n$.

Comment: @Portland, in dimension 2, for $p$ close to $1$ and $q$ close to infinity, equality cannot be valid by continuity. (The optimal $A$ will be a 45 degree rotation, unlike the estimate given, which corresponds to $A$ being the identity.)